# Passing final parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently developing a flutter project to **scrape** an article from the internet. I'm having a little trouble because i'm trying to copy a guy from youtube (links below) but using my style for the UI.

I want to copy the steps to scrape the website with his steps https://youtu.be/S4lB5Q9wM_s?t=546 but i'm having a little trouble like this :

```
home page
```

```
import 'package:artickle/pages/ArticlePage.dart';
import 'package:artickle/pages/FavoritesPage.dart';
import 'package:artickle/pages/HistoryPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(initialIndex: 1, vsync: this, length: 3);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Artickle'),
          elevation: 0.7,
          actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: (){},
              ),
            ],
            bottom: new TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                new Tab(child: new Text("Article", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button)),
                new Tab(child: new Text("Favorite", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button)),
                new Tab(child: new Text("History", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button)),
            ],
        ),
    ),
        body: new TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController ,
            children: <Widget>[
              new ArticlePage(ArticlePage.name), -> error
              new FavoritesPage(),
              new HistoryPage()
            ]
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Article page
```

```
class ArticlePage extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  State createState() => ArticlePageState();
  final String name;
  ArticlePage(this.name);
}

class ArticlePageState extends State<ArticlePage>{

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getdata();
  }

  getdata()async{
    var url = 'https://www.***.com/artikel/${widget.name}/';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
    final mainclass = document.getElementsByClassName('sc-htpNat eGAHHA');
    print(mainclass);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("${widget.name} quotes", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)
          ],
        ),

      )
    );

  }


}
```

The problem is in the body on the home page there's an error

> "Instance member 'name' cannot be accsessed using static access"

Comment: 'ArticlePage.name' I don't know exactly what you want this code. Just pass the String type parameter. ex) 'Article'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what you've stated.

`ArticlePage.name` is a *static reference*. There's no instance involved. Instead, you should use a String, since that is the type for the instance field "name". Replace ArticlePage.name with 'Article Name' <- make sure to include the quotes.

Alternatively, you could make the name field static by putting `static String name = 'Article Page Name';`

This will make the name always the same - it's static, aka not dynamic, not changing